Reducing Size when exporting an STL mesh from trimesh
I am exporting tens or hundreds of tiny individual meshes that form a larger part into an STL file, using trimesh.
I create my meshes, then I add them all into a scene, and export the scene.
I've tried quadric decimation, and reducing the sections of primitive objects (cylinders, cones, etc.) But I am not sure what else to do.
I've also ran checks to see if somehow duplicate objects were being made, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.
